# Magento 2.1 creating a slider / Carousal

Tags: magento-2.1, banner-slider

I have a two part question:

1. How would i go about writing a block/widget (bespoke code that would allow me to output some html that made use of jquery and bespoke css) that implements code to produce a carousal - I know how this could be done say on a plain HTML page, but then Magento has its own idiosyncrasies?
2. Does anyone know a decent resource which would be a really good place to start to learn how Magento 2.1 works and how to develop for it, starting from the basics with good analogies as a posed to talking from an advanced level of programming?

A lot of the resources I have come across assume an experienced developer is reading their page - rather than a beginner